# Calling `setOnAction` from another class

Tags: java, javafx

When adding a JavaFX button by code, how can I call the `.setOnAction` method of the button from another class.

For instance, if I was to handle the button press within the same class:

```
public class SomeClass{
    Button continueButton = new Button("Continue");
    continueButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            someMethod();
        }
    });
}
```

However if I wish to utilise a controller for this, how can 'link' the actionEvent to a method within the other class.

 eg:

```
public class SomeClass{
    private SomeClassController controller;
    Button continueButton = new Button("Continue");
    continueButton.setOnAction(
        //Call continuePressed() on controller
    );
}

public class SomeClassController{
    public void continuePressed(){
        someMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: [`setOnAction()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ButtonBase.html#setOnAction-javafx.event.EventHandler-) expects a [`EventHandler<ActionEvent>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/EventHandler.html) which is an interface. So, when you trying to create an anonymous class from it, you need to override the `handle()` method.

Comment: I do not completely understand your question. Why can't you call `controller.someMethod()` from your handle()? Is the instance of `SomeClassController` not effectively final?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
public class SomeClass{
    SomeClassController ctrl = new SomeClassController();
    Button continueButton = new Button("Continue");
    continueButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            ctrl.someMethod();
        }
    });
}
```

Then the event handler is attach to the button but its triggering call a method from your controller

---

Or:

```
public class SomeClass{
    SomeClassController ctrl = new SomeClassController();
    private SomeClassController controller;
    Button continueButton = new Button("Continue");
    continueButton.setOnAction(ctrl.getHandler());
}

public class SomeClassController{

   private EventHandler<ActionEvent> EH;

   public SomeClassController(){
       EH = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
           @Override
           public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
              someMethod();
           }
       });
}

public EventHandler<ActionEvent> getHandler(){
return EH;
}

public void someMethod(){
//DO SOMETHING
}
}
```

I didn't test the code...

Comment: So I still need to put `handle(ActionEvent event)` no matter what? It seems logical to be able to replace the `handle` with a custom method, rather than calling `handle` and the another method from that.

Comment: No you could create the EventHandler in the controller and get it in your setOnAction method. I will update my code

Answer (score 1):

Barbe Rouge is right. A somewhat simpler solution using Java 8 syntax would be:

```
public class SomeClass {

    private final SomeClassController controller = new SomeClassController();

    public SomeClass() {
        final Button button = new Button("Click me!");
        button.setOnAction(controller::handle);
    }

}

public class SomeClassController {
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```