# Access data from another class

Tags: java, user-interface

I've been trying to code *TicTacToe* with a graphical Interface to understand JavaFX better. The problem arises when I try to access the button and `b1.setOnAction()` in my *TicTacToe* class, from my Graphics class.

```
public class Graphics extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {

    GridPane gp = new GridPane();       

    Button b1 = new Button();
    b1.setPrefSize(50, 50);
    gp.add(b1, 2, 2);   

    Scene scene = new Scene(gp, 230, 250);
    stage.setTitle("TicTacToe");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();     
   }
}
```

Graphics on its own works and creates a Windows with all the necessary buttons I need, if I implement a main method with launch (args). If the `b1.setOnAction()` method is in here I also can access the buttons.

```
public class TicTacToe {

public void game() {

    // This doesnt work, it just visualizes my problem...
    b1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            b1.setText("X");
        }
    });
  }
}
```

In *TicTacToe* I want access to all the buttons whenever I want, but I have no idea how this works. I tried to google my question, but no answer could fix my code.

(I tried to delete as much as possible in the code to simplify things. If something important is missing out, please tell me and I will add it.)

**TL;DR** I want to access the buttons from my Graphics class in my *TicTacToe* class whenever I want to perform an action.

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32776970/calling-setonaction-from-another-class)

Comment: if you want to access `Graphics` button `b1`  make  `Button b1` a field (class variable) and add a getter to  `Graphics` like `public Button getButton(){return b1;}`

Comment: I think your issue is not about JavaFX at all. It's simply a matter of not knowing how to access data from one class in another class. The key is to put the data in *fields* rather than local variables, and create getters and setters for those fields.

Comment: I tired this... but i cant access the b1.setAtion() from TicTacToe

Comment: + I get an InvocationTargetException if i try to create a Constructor in Graphics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Graphics extends Application {

    private Button b1;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        GridPane gp = new GridPane();       
        b1 = new Button();
        b1.setPrefSize(50, 50);
        gp.add(b1, 2, 2);   

        Scene scene = new Scene(gp, 230, 250);
        stage.setTitle("TicTacToe");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();     
    }

    public Button getButton(){return b1;}
}

class TicTacToe {

    Graphics g;
    public TicTacToe() {

        //If you don't want to create Graphics here, get a reference to it 
        g = new Graphics();
    }

    public void game() {

        g.getButton().setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() { 
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                //do what you need 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Edit:  I am not sure what you want to do, but you may want to have `Graphics` construct `TicTacToe`:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Graphics extends Application {

    public Graphics() {

        new TicTacToe(this);
    }

    private Button b1;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        GridPane gp = new GridPane();
        b1 = new Button();
        b1.setPrefSize(50, 50);
        gp.add(b1, 2, 2);

        Scene scene = new Scene(gp, 230, 250);
        stage.setTitle("TicTacToe");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public Button getButton(){return b1;}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);
    }
}

class TicTacToe {

    Graphics g;

    public TicTacToe(Graphics g) {

        this.g = g;
    }

    public void game() {

        /**
            g.getButton().setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    //do what you need
                }
            });*/
        //if you wan to set buttons text :
        g.getButton().setText("X");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you thats helpful. But how do i launch the application in TicTacToe ? g.launch(null); doesnt work. I get a NullPointerException.

Comment: This is an interesting idea, i m gonna try that. Thx for answering :)